# Sending attachment on webforms with drupal 7

Tags: webforms, emails

Dears,

I have a webform where quest can send a attachment. For registered users this works bit for guest they send the mail whitout an attachment. The file is uploaded in the webform folder. How can I fix this taht the file is send with the email?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of Webform ver. 7.x-4.14. Try to use 7.x-4.x-dev version of webform or apply patch #2 from https://www.drupal.org/node/2675170

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the drupal 7 core to the latest version and this fixed my issue. You directed me in the right direction